# Silverlight C# .net: textbox text deletion issue

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a silverlight application in C#.net. 
I have a textbox on the screen which is used to perform search.

The issue is, when i type some text in it and then try to delete the text by selecting the entire text in the textbox by mouse click and drag, it doesn't do any thing. I'm not even able to type any text in it.
What i have noticed is this happens only if the cursor has moved out of the browser frame (on which silverlight application resides) as i select the text in the text box.

Please excuse me if i have not explained the issue clearly, or if any other information is needed.

silverlight version 4.0 and Browser EI8

Regards

Comment: Is there a chance that the website handles the keyboard events, so Silverlight never gets notified about them?

Comment: No Gene, no such events in the application

Comment: What version of Silverlight are you using in what browser?

Comment: silverlight version 4.0 and Browser EI8

Comment: Is there any way that the textbox is set to readonly?

Comment: Well, I have had some similar issues with firefox, but have you tried uninstalling Silverlight and installing it again?

Comment: I have another application on silverlight which works fine. SO i dont think re-installing would help

Comment: Have you edited the original textbox template at all?

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly need!